Knowing position of keys on keyboard
When I type on a QWERTY keyboard, I know exactly where to find my letters in a split-second, without even watching. Then why don't I know the order of the keys by heart?
What kind of automatic or unconscious knowledge is at work?

If you were to attempt to throw a ball, you could likely do it without any problem, yet try to name or even merely point to all the muscles involved and the timing and amplitude of the tension in each: this would be impossible (remember that it won't be limited to muscles in your arm or shoulder; you'll be using pretty much every muscle in your body to some extent).
This is referred to as muscle memory and learning these skills is motor learning.
In contrast, explicit or declarative memory is the type of memory involving conscious recall of facts. These are physically separate learning systems in the brain, so you can have one without the other.
